# Arduino Yun, node.js and serial

Tags: serial, arduino-yun

I'm trying to bypass Bridge library and read serial directly from nodejs. I'm on the last sys upgrade (1.3) I have correctly installed nodes and serial module via opkg install. I have also commented out the line in the `/etc/inittab`:

```
#ttyATH0::askfirst:/bin/ash --login
```

This is my arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("dudee");
  delay(100);
}
```

This is my node.js code:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyATH0", {
    baudrate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
}, false);

console.log("hello");

serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data received: ' + data);
    });
});

serialPort.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error: '+err);
});

serialPort.open();
```

If I ssh to yun and run the script I don't see any "dudee":

```
~/test# node serial.js
hello
open
```

While if I open the serial monitor I see it.

If I run the node script on my computer (changing the right serial port name) everything works nice and I see the dude..

What can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autosolved thanks to [this old forum post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=194934.15).

It is `Serial1` not `Serial`.
In the Arduino code in the Yun `Serial` is a different object from `Serial1`. Even if it is not super well document (or at least not in the first dumb google search) here are some links that talks about `Serial1`:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunSerialTerminal
http://andrea-toscano.com/arduino-yun-tcpip-to-serial1-redirect/
http://crossbar.io/iotcookbook/Arduino-Yun-Disable-Bridge/

Comment: Thanks man, this was really helpfull, as I had the same issue.

Comment: @nkint would you like to elaborate how did the post help you? Your answer would be good for other seekers.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava: it is only a different object in the arduino side.. `Serial` is different from `Serial1` int he Yun..